# How can I reinitialize a datatable in React?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, datatables

I am trying to create a table in my react app that has column reordering, selecting rows, drag+drop row reordering, and more. so a complex table. I am trying to do this with datatables jquery. I am working on a react component 'Table.js' to do so. So far my example datatable works, but when i refresh the page or the dm reloads due to a change in my codesandbox code, I get an error message saying

> datatables warning table id = Datatables_table_0 cannot reinitialise datatable. for more info abt this err please see datatables.net/tn/3

https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-elion-vt1sg3?file=/src/App.js

i call my Table.js from inside App.js here:

```
import React from "react";
import Table from "./Table";

function App() {
  let tableData = [
    ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
    ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
  ];
  return (
    <>
      <h2>Hello</h2>

      <Table tableData={tableData} />
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

but am i rendering my datatable correctly? or is this error something that only happens in codesandbox? I definitely need to fix my code so that this popup error doesnt occur every time there is a change

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import $ from "jquery";
import DataTable from "datatables.net-dt";
import "datatables.net-rowreorder-dt"; // import the rowreorder extension

import "./Table.css";

const Table = ({ tableData }) => {
    
    //call tableSetup function once on startup
    useEffect(() => {
        tableSetup();
    }, []);

    //call function to update table data 
    useEffect(() => {
        updateTableRows(tableData)
    }, [tableData]);

    const updateTableRows = (newData) => {
        console.log('adding data to table: ', newData)
        var $el = $(tableRef.current);
        var dataTable = $el.DataTable();
        dataTable.clear()
        for(var x=0; x<newData.length; x++){
            console.log(`add row ${x}: `, newData[x])
            dataTable.row.add(newData[x]);
        }
        dataTable.draw();
      };

    const tableRef = useRef();
    const tableSetup = () => {
        const $el = $(tableRef.current);
        const dataTable = $el.DataTable({
            columns: [
                { title: "sequence" },
                { title: "#" },
                { title: "<input type='checkbox'>", orderable: false },
                { title: "audio", className: "track-name", type: "natural" },
            ],
            columnDefs: [
                { targets: [0], searchable: false, orderable: false, visible: false },
                { targets: [1], searchable: false, orderable: false, width: "40px" },
                { targets: [2], className: "selectall-checkbox text-center", searchable: false, orderable: false, width: "40px" },
            ],
            autoWidth: true,
            language: {
                emptyTable: "No files in this upload",
            },
            rowReorder: {
                dataSrc: "sequence",
            },
        });
        return () => {
            dataTable.destroy(true);
        };
    }

    return (
        <table ref={tableRef} style={{ width: "100%" }}>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>sequence</th>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>selectAll</th>
                    <th>audio</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    );
};

export default Table;
```

Comment: Please don't tag your title. See [ask].

Comment: You can add `retrieve: true` to your `tableSetup` options, for example, like before or after `autoWidth: true,`

Answer (score 0):

You can add retrieve: true to your tableSetup options, for example, like before or after autoWidth: true, –
Hackerman